# SQL - Group by numbers according to their difference

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

I have a table and I want to group rows that have at most x difference at col2.
For example,

```
col1   col2
abg    3
abw    4
abc    5
abd    6
abe    20
abf    21
```

After query I want to get  groups such that

```
group 1:  abg    3
          abw    4
          abc    5
          abd    6

group 2: abe 20
         abf 21
```

In this example difference is 1.

How can write such a query?

Comment: Should 3, 4, 5, 6 be also grouped in a single group? Or 2 groups? (3+4, 5+6) Or 3 groups? (3+4, 4+5, 5+6) Maybe you could provide a bigger example, this one is a bit ambiguous to me.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: have you tried NTILE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Oracle (or anything that supports window functions) this will work:

```
select col1, col2, sum(group_gen) over (order by col2) as grp
from (
  select col1, col2,
         case when col2 - lag(col2) over (order by col2) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as group_gen
  from some_table
)
```

Check it on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f541/1).

Answer (score 1):

This should get what you need, and changing the gap to that of 5, or any other number is a single change at the @lastVal +1 (vs whatever other difference).  The prequery "PreSorted" is required to make sure the data is being processed sequentially so you don't get out-of-order entries.

As each current row is processed, it's column 2 value is stored in the @lastVal for test comparison of the next row, but remains as a valid column "Col2".  There is no "group by" as you are just wanting a column to identify where each group is associated vs any aggregation.

```
select
      @grp := if( PreSorted.col2 > @lastVal +1, @grp +1, @grp ) as GapGroup,
      PreSorted.col1,
      @lastVal := PreSorted.col2 as Col2
   from
      ( select
              YT.col1,
              YT.col2
           from
              YourTable YT
           order by
              YT.col2 ) PreSorted,
      ( select @grp := 1,
               @lastVal := -1 ) sqlvars
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query, you can use 1 and 2 as input and get you groups:

```
var grp number(5)
exec :grp :=1 
select * from YourTABLE
where (:grp = 1 and col2 < 20) or (:grp = 2 and col2 > 6);
```